# Registros de eventos de Instagram

Tags: instagram, events

En la ruta time_in_app exsite una tabla con informacion sobre el número de secuencia, tiempo que se ha generado y start_event con end_event. Necesito saber que significa el número que se le asigna a estos eventos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.